# Minimization parameters on machine learning

Tags: machine-learning

Hello I'm studying machine learning processes and I'm beside of a misunderstanding..

**Is this right?**

> "Minimization is a process that minimize the error rate of Y (output
>   of the feature) to be a valid limiter and this is followed by an
>   optimization process that acts on the parameters to find the best ones
>   for the best model to choose"

The only parameters I know in my head now are the FEATURES (X inputs).
Which are the parameters to optimize? Technical parameters?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Where did this quote come from? It doesn't make much sense to me either.

Comment: @gung Damn.. that was what I realized. Can you help me to undestand please? :)

Comment: Was this quotation originally rendered in a language other than English and then translated?

Comment: Think about a “multi-purpose box” waiting for input and producing the corre- sponding output depending on operations influenced by internal parameters. The information to be used for “customizing” the box has to be extracted from the given training examples. The basic idea is to fix the free parameters by demanding that the learned model works correctly on the examples in the training set.
Now, we are all believers in the power of optimization: we start by defining an error measure to be minimized1, and we adopt an appropriate (automated) opti- mization process to determine optimal parameters.

Comment: what kind of parameters? features or other parameters? Excuse me but I guess I'm really confused

Comment: parameters in optimization usually refers to model parameters, simple example is you would identify coefficients aka parameters in multiple linear regression by minimizing least squares of mean squared error using an optimization algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me explain that for you.

Every model has some unknowns that are called parameters. For example, if $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ are some features then a simple model can be like $Y=b_1X_1+\ldots+b_nX_n +e$ where $e$ is the error that is bounded (simply $var(e)<\infty$). Then the goal of optimization is to find (or estimate) a set of parameters, $b_1,\ldots,b_n$ that minimizes a certain criteria, like $\sum e^2$. If you have a set of measurements from the features, then using optimization techniques you can estimate parameters numerically.

PS: parameters can be coefficients, distribution unknown (like mean, var ...), risks and .... . Thus a parameter is a part of model and it is not something individual.

Comment: Ok.. so minimization should minimize the "e" value to the maximum error rate accepted?

Comment: minimum error rate, yes. Note that $e=y-b_1X_1-\ldots-b_nX_n$

Answer (score 0):

You can see your machine learning solution as a black box. The black box has a number of knobs which you can easily tune. The performance of your solution depend how these knobs are set. You can set them at random, you can set them manually or let an optimization algorithm to set them. In most cases you want the latter.